# How to reset the count number of lines in each file using PHP

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, line-numbers

I have a PHP code that reads multiple txt files and search for user request for a word  if the word exist the code will display the the requested word with the line number and the file name.

the code work perfect but  the problem is in the line number  because the system take all the txt file and combine it in one file and continue counting the line number .

what i want is to   make the system start from the first line in each file

example :

word محلي exist in 7 files on the same line 13 
the system display this :

- the word محلّي exist on line [13] in 4-4-2017.txt
- the word محلّي exist on line [77] in arabic text.txt
- the word محلّي exist on line [175] in XXXX10-4-2017.txt
- the word محلّي exist on line [240] in XXXX5-4-2017.txt
- the word محلّي exist on line [302] in XXXX6-4-2017.txt
- the word محلّي exist on line [367] in XXXX7-4-2017.txt
- the word محلّي exist on line [431] in XXXX-08-04-2017.txt

yet this word exist on all these file on line 13

## code:

```
<?php

$line = 1; 

if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $search =$_POST['name'];
foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/*.txt") as $txts)
  {
    $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');

    while(!feof($myFileLink)) 
    { 
     $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
     if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
     {

        foreach($matches[1] as $match)
        {
           echo "the word  $match exist on line [$line] in  ";

        }
        echo basename ($txts) . "<br>".PHP_EOL;
     //++$line;
     }

     ++$line;

    }


  fclose($myFileLink);

  }
}

?>


<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <body>
     <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <p>enter your string <input type ="text"  id = "idName"  name="name" /></p>
          <p><input type ="Submit" name ="search" value= "Search" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $line = 1;  remove this line from the begning and add inside the foreach loop before $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');

Comment: @AlamDarji thank you for your help .

if i want to just display the requested word one time like a title and then the places where it exist  how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change Your PHP Code to this. Hope this will help.

```
<?php 
$line = 1;
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $search =$_POST['name'];
    echo "the word  $search exist on <br><br>";
    foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/*.txt") as $txts)
    {
        $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');
        while(!feof($myFileLink)) 
        {
            $files[] = basename($txts);
            $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
            if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
            {
                foreach($matches[1] as $match)
                {
                    //echo "line [$line] in  ";
                    $lines[str_replace(" ", "_", basename($txts))][] = $line;
                }
                //echo basename($txts) . "<br>".PHP_EOL;
            }
            ++$line;
        }
    fclose($myFileLink);
    }
}
?>
```

and in the body add this

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["search"]) && !empty($files)): ?>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>File Name</td>
            <td>Line No.</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($files as $name): ?>
                <td><?= $name; ?></td>
                <td><?= implode(', ', $lines[str_replace(" ", "_", $name)]); ?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: your code work perfect but it still display error in some lines.

after i search for this string the system display :

the word النظام exist on

line [57] in 4-4-2017.txt
line [58] in 4-4-2017.txt
line [62] in line [62] in 4-4-2017.txt

============= the last line is malformed

Comment: It might me matching the word twice in the last line {line [62] in line [62] in 4-4-2017.txt }

Comment: yes you were right ..
 i have a question if i have more than 1000 file is this code will work ?

Comment: but it will not be very slow in reading and matching for string ??

Comment: depending upon the number of files in the folder it will take time but it will work absolutely fine.

Comment: can you help me with this question 

if i want after the search  to display all the files with line numbers in a table ...like    the table column header will be the file name and the rows will be the line number

Comment: I don't think that is possible as the number of occurrence of the string matching will be different for different file and that will cause a problem in the structure of the table.

Comment: oh okk now it make sense ... but how to display  the result in a good format ?

Comment: Displaying the searches result in table it's not possible.

Comment: Just wait for some time will give it a try.

Comment: @ Alam Darji  you mean the body of the HTML ?

because i tried your code it did not workk it display the result in bade shape.... 
also it display these error :
**Notice: Undefined index: arabic text2.txt in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 50
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 50**

Comment: Yes body of the HTML... try giving borders to the table <table border="1">

Comment: answer updated. check please these two lines changed.

{ $lines[str_replace(" ", "_", basename($txts))][] = $line; } and   

{ <td><?= implode(', ', $lines[str_replace("_", " ", $name)]); ?></td> }